# Mockito - how to answer with custom object

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, mockito

Trying to test the construction like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = POST)
public ResponseEntity test(@RequestBody TestRequest request, Errors errors) {

    testValidator.validate(request, errors); // Spring Validator interface impl


    if (errors.hasErrors())
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The `Errors` object is passed by framework and not by me, so there's no better way to change it's behaviour for the test except of using something like Mockito's `Answer`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @MockBean
    private TestValidator testValidator; 

    @Test
    public void test() {

        doAnswer(new Answer<Errors>() {

           @Override
           public Errors answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {

             Errors errors = spy((Errors) invocation.getArguments()[1]);
             //errors.rejectValue("id", "id", "id rejected");

             doReturn(true).when(errors).hasErrors();

             return errors;
         }

      }).when(testValidator).validate(any(), any());

      ResponseEntity re = testRestTemplate
        .postForEntity("/test", new TestRequest(213L), String.class);

      assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, re.getStatusCode());
  }
```

... but the problem is `errors.hasErrors()` still returns `false` despite on `doAnswer` test block and the assertion fails because of HTTP status `OK`. I expect the `Errors` object will become the spy with specified behaviour right after `.validate()` call but seems I'm doing something wrong.

So, how to return a custom object using Mockito's `doAnswer`?

Comment: The way you did, how do you "inject" your testValidator into the tested instance?

Comment: (I would also suggest you to use spring-mvc-test)

Comment: @RC., using the new Spring testing feature `@MockBean` annotation that behaves exactly like Mockito's `@Mock` does

Comment: @RC., the approach seems to be deprecated due to introducted by Spring another `slice` approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `postForEntity` in your test, because that makes it an integration test  of the framework itself, plus the actual class that you're testing.

Just make your own `Errors` object, which may or may not be a mock.  If it's a mock, then you can set it up as follows.

```
doReturn(true).when(mockErrors).hasErrors();
```

Then your test can look like this.

```
@Test
public void test() {
  ResponseEntity re = objectThatYoureTesting.test(mockTestRequest, mockErrors);
  assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, re.getStatusCode());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`doReturn(true).when(errors).hasErrors()` works only if the code block uses spied `errors` instance. If you assign the returned `Error` reference to the variable, mock should work:

```
errors = testValidator.validate(request, errors);
```

You will add this assignment just for test purposes, but it is also good for code readability; it strongly indicates `errors` instance is modified inside the `validate` method.

**UPDATE**: You can wrap the validator to return the errors, than you can spy the wrapped validator:

```
public class ValidatorWrapper {
    public Errors validate(TestRequest request, Errors errors) {
        testValidator.validate(request, errors);
        return errors;
    }
}
```

And test code will be similar to:

```
controller.setValidatorWrapper(spiedValidatorWrapper);
doAnswer(new Answer<Errors>() {

       @Override
       public Errors answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {

         Errors errors = spy((Errors) invocation.getArguments()[1]);
         //errors.rejectValue("id", "id", "id rejected");

         doReturn(true).when(errors).hasErrors();

         return errors;
     }

  }).when(spiedValidatorWrapper).validate(any(), any());
 //rest of the test
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: hm `testValidator` is Spring Validator interface implementation, that's why there's no option to use return value

Comment: I assumed there is one because you returned it in the answer block. Then there is no way to spy the `Error` instance.